# Optimisation Crawler Scrapy

Tags: python, sql, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using scrapy to find expired domains, my crawler crawl the web and add every externals domains to the database (MySql) and after I check the availability with a PHP script.

The database have around 300k domains and now the crawler is very slow because I check before each insert if the domain is not into the database yet with this request

**SQL request of the insert_table() method :**

```
sql = "INSERT INTO %s (url) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '%s') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT url FROM website WHERE url = '%s' ) LIMIT 1"  % (SQL_TABLE, datas, datas)
```

**The Crawler :**

```
class HttpbinSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "expired"

    start_urls = [
        'http://mywebsite.com',
    ]

    custom_settings = {
        'RETRY_ENABLED': True,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT' : 0,
        'DEPTH_PRIORITY' : 1,
        'LOG_ENABLED' : False,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN' : 32,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' : 64,
    }

    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()),
            callback='parse_obj',
            follow=True),)

    def parse_obj(self,response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = []
        for link in LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.com', '.fr', '.net', '.org', '.info'),
            deny=('facebook', 'amazon', 'wordpress'),).extract_links(response):   
            ext = tldextract.extract(link.url)
            insert_table(ext.registered_domain)
```

Can someone help me to find solutions to get expired domains why my crawler and keep the best performances.

Thank's

Comment: Do you have an index on the url column?

Comment: No I don't have an index on the url.

Comment: Given that every query does a compare with the url column would it be worth adding an index? I would have thought that would increase the speed.

Answer (score 0):

You have really bad sql query. 
Add a unique key for a column url and ignore on duplicate that will speed up inserting. Unique index will work for you.

Select is unnecessary.